# Http request doesnot take the input value

Tags: angular, api, http

**File Structure image**

[image]

```
export class FaqService {
public inputValue;
constructor(private http: Http) {}

ngOnInit() {}

setData(val) {
 this.inputValue = val;
    console.log(this.inputValue);
}

getData() {
    return this.inputValue;
}

getServers() {
    return this.http.get(Staticdata.apiBaseUrl + "/2.2/search/advanced?key="+ Staticdata.key +"&access_token="+ Staticdata.access_token +"&/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&closed=True&title=" + this.inputValue + Staticdata.redirectUrl + "&filter="+ Staticdata.filters)
        .map(
        (response: Response) => {
            const items = response.json();
            return items;
        },
    )
    .catch(
        (error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }
  );
}
}
```

In the above class I get data in a method `setData()` from a parent component and I am not able to pass fetched value to the `http get request`.

The Http get request goes in this way: `order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&closed=True&title=undefined&site=stackoverflow` .

In title field it takes undefined as value.

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { FaqService } from '../faq.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-search-results',
 templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css'],
 providers: [FaqService]
})

 export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
 data: any[];
 item: any[];

 constructor(private faqService: FaqService) {
 }
 ngOnInit() {

  this.faqService.getServers()
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.item = data.items;
            console.log(this.item);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
    );
}  
}
```

Here i call the `getServers()` method in child component.
Thank you in advance.

**faq.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" placeholder="Search FAQ" type="text"/>
<button type="submit" id="headerSearchbutton"  (click)="onRecievingResults(inputValue)"></button>
```

here i take input using ngModel and pass the value to the `onRecievingResults` function.

```
 onRecievingResults(value) {
    this.faqService.setData(value);
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the data? Where do you call `getServers`?

Comment: are you certain `getServers` will call after  `setData`  called

Comment: No  i am not sure about that .pls suggest any solution if u have. @sachilaranawaka

Comment: I call the getServers in child component this.faqService.getServers()
            .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.item = data.items;
                console.log(this.item);
            },
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );

Comment: post the code where u call the following methods

Comment: changes made in the above post @sachilaranawaka

Comment: where do you call `setData` methods

Comment: File structure image added above@sachilaranawaka

Comment: All the details mentioned above pls go through it @echonax

Comment: all details added neatly. plz help me to solve this.@sachilaranawaka

Comment: I see the @Injectable() decorator missing before your FaqService. Its better to create a plunk for your problem.

Comment: i have @injectable() decorator @Faisal

Answer (score 0):

@Samson, if I understand the sequence of events correctly, inputValue is undefined in the FaqService because getServers() is called *before* setData() is called. The component calls getServers() from its ngOnInit() method, but it doesn't call setData() until the headerSearchbutton is clicked.

It seems the point of getServers() is to perform a search based on whatever the user has typed into the  field, no? If so, instead of calling getServers() from the component's ngOnInit(), why not call it when the button is clicked, in onRecievingResults?

Comment: Because I want results in other component so i cant call it in onRecievingResults()